# Why isn't my docker container respecting my permissions?

Tags: bash, docker, permissions

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt install -y bash

CMD []
```

build and run:

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -it test bash
```

minimal reproduction:

```
root@8807902e27b4:/# mkdir parent
root@8807902e27b4:/# cd parent
root@8807902e27b4:/parent# mkdir example
root@8807902e27b4:/parent# chmod 000 example
root@8807902e27b4:/parent# ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 28 19:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Apr 28 19:32 ..
d--------- 2 root root 4096 Apr 28 19:33 example
root@8807902e27b4:/parent# cd example
root@8807902e27b4:/parent/example# echo "test" > test.txt
root@8807902e27b4:/parent/example# chmod 100 test.txt
root@8807902e27b4:/parent/example# cat test.txt
test
root@8807902e27b4:/parent/example# ls -la
total 12
d--------- 2 root root 4096 Apr 28 19:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 28 19:33 ..
---x------ 1 root root    5 Apr 28 19:33 test.txt
```

In the above example, the `cd example` command should fail, and even if it doesn't, running `cat test.txt` should fail. Anyone know what's up?

Here are the same (working) commands run in osx:

```
beaushinkle@Beaus-MBP ~/p/example-docker> mkdir parent
beaushinkle@Beaus-MBP ~/p/example-docker> cd parent
beaushinkle@Beaus-MBP ~/p/e/parent> mkdir example
beaushinkle@Beaus-MBP ~/p/e/parent> chmod 000 example
beaushinkle@Beaus-MBP ~/p/e/parent> cd example
cd: Permission denied: 'example'
beaushinkle@Beaus-MBP ~/p/e/parent [1]> chmod 777 example
beaushinkle@Beaus-MBP ~/p/e/parent> cd example
beaushinkle@Beaus-MBP ~/p/e/p/example> echo "test" > test.txt
beaushinkle@Beaus-MBP ~/p/e/p/example> chmod 100 test.txt
beaushinkle@Beaus-MBP ~/p/e/p/example> cat test.txt
cat: test.txt: Permission denied
```

Comment: In the minimal reproduction, we are logged-in as `root` if the prompt is accurate. `root` has implicit access to everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the prompt is anything to go by, we are logged in as `root` in the minimal reproduction. Thus, we have [root privileges and can read and write all files (external link)](https://www.ssh.com/academy/iam/user/root#root-privileges).